# Pandas: combine multiple rows into one row based on index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Q10: HEDGE FUND':['NO', 'YES', 'NO'],
                   'Q10: PRIVATE EQUITY FUND': ['NO', 'YES', 'YES'],
                   'Q10: REAL ESTATE FUND': ['YES', 'NO', 'NO']}).T

                            0    1    2
Q10: HEDGE FUND            NO  YES   NO
Q10: PRIVATE EQUITY FUND   NO  YES  YES
Q10: REAL ESTATE FUND     YES   NO   NO
```

**What I want:**

```
                    0    1                    2
Q10  REAL ESTATE FUND  N/A  PRIVATE EQUITY FUND
```

That is, I want to take the three Q10 rows and combine them into 1, listing the type of fund.

Each column corresponds to a type of fund. Column 0 is a Real Estate Fund (notice that there's a YES in the Q10: REAL ESTATE FUND row). Column 2 is a Private Equity Fund (notice there's a YES in the Q10: PRIVATE EQUITY row). Column 1, however, lists has two YESes, which is an error in the dataframe. I need to change this to N/A.

What I've tried: for each column I can locate the position of the 'YES' in each column, but I dont know how to deal with column 1 (which has two yeses, so should be changed to N/A) and I feel there's a more seamless way of doing this:

```
df[0].tolist().index('YES')
2
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what your columns mean and what your wanted output is

Comment: I've added some more explanation, hope this helps. Each column is a different "fund" and the rows tell which type of fund it is (with the exception of column 1, which is an error in the dataframe). I want to change this from 3 YES/NO rows to 1 row that lists the type of fund

Comment: So if there are multiple YES in a column they all need to be changed to NO basically? And then see which columns are yes?

Comment: No, if there are multiple Yes in a column this is an error, so the row in the new dataframe needs to read N/A, like in the example I gave (see What I want:)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Q10: HEDGE FUND':['NO', 'YES', 'NO'],
               'Q10: PRIVATE EQUITY FUND': ['NO', 'YES', 'YES'],
               'Q10: REAL ESTATE FUND': ['YES', 'NO', 'NO']}).T

df2 = pd.DataFrame(index = ["Q10"], columns = [0,1,2])

df = df.transpose()
Row = []
for col in df.columns:
   if df[col].value_counts()["YES"]==1:
       Row.append(col[5:])
   else:
       Row.append("N/A")

df2.loc["Q10"] = Row
```